# How to check that multiplication of two decimal numbers is greater than ULONG_MAX?

Tags: c++, c

I need to write a function that returns **true** if the multiplication of two numbers is greater than **ULONG_MAX** limit. Otherwise returns **false**.

I tried the following method:

```
bool isGtThanULONG_MAX(double A, double B) {
    double result = A * B;
    if (result > ULONG_MAX)
        return true;
    else
    {
        //If this could be due to overflow, then again check:
        double temp = result / A;
        
        if (A != 0 && (temp != B)) {
        // overflow handling
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

**output:** 1st and 4th line in below cout statements are giving OVERFLOW (which is obviously wrong output) and rest are giving NO-OVERFLOW (which is correct) in output.
Why it is failing? am I missing anything? please help.

```
    cout << (isGtThanULONG_MAX(10, 0.0000000000000000001) == true ? "OVERFLOW" : "NO-OVERFLOW") << endl;//OVERFLOW
    cout << (isGtThanULONG_MAX(10, 0.000000000000000001) == true ? "OVERFLOW" : "NO-OVERFLOW") << endl;
    cout << (isGtThanULONG_MAX(10, 0.00000000000000001) == true ? "OVERFLOW" : "NO-OVERFLOW") << endl;
    cout << (isGtThanULONG_MAX(10, 0.0000000000000001) == true ? "OVERFLOW" : "NO-OVERFLOW") << endl;//OVERFLOW
    cout << (isGtThanULONG_MAX(10, 0.000000000000001) == true ? "OVERFLOW" : "NO-OVERFLOW") << endl;
    cout << (isGtThanULONG_MAX(10, 0.00000000000001) == true ? "OVERFLOW" : "NO-OVERFLOW") << endl;
    cout << (isGtThanULONG_MAX(10, 0.0000000000001) == true ? "OVERFLOW" : "NO-OVERFLOW") << endl;
    cout << (isGtThanULONG_MAX(10, 0.000000000001) == true ? "OVERFLOW" : "NO-OVERFLOW") << endl;
    cout << (isGtThanULONG_MAX(10, 0.00000000001) == true ? "OVERFLOW" : "NO-OVERFLOW") << endl;
    cout << (isGtThanULONG_MAX(10, 0.0000000001) == true ? "OVERFLOW" : "NO-OVERFLOW") << endl;
    cout << (isGtThanULONG_MAX(10, 0.000000001) == true ? "OVERFLOW" : "NO-OVERFLOW") << endl;
    cout << (isGtThanULONG_MAX(10, 0.00000001) == true ? "OVERFLOW" : "NO-OVERFLOW") << endl;
    cout << (isGtThanULONG_MAX(10, 0.0000001) == true ? "OVERFLOW" : "NO-OVERFLOW") << endl;
    cout << (isGtThanULONG_MAX(10, 0.000001) == true ? "OVERFLOW" : "NO-OVERFLOW") << endl;
    cout << (isGtThanULONG_MAX(10, 0.00001) == true ? "OVERFLOW" : "NO-OVERFLOW") << endl;
    cout << (isGtThanULONG_MAX(10, 0.0001) == true ? "OVERFLOW" : "NO-OVERFLOW") << endl;
    cout << (isGtThanULONG_MAX(10, 0.001) == true ? "OVERFLOW" : "NO-OVERFLOW") << endl;
    cout << (isGtThanULONG_MAX(10, 0.01) == true ? "OVERFLOW" : "NO-OVERFLOW") << endl;
    cout << (isGtThanULONG_MAX(10, 0.1) == true ? "OVERFLOW" : "NO-OVERFLOW") << endl;
    cout << (isGtThanULONG_MAX(10, 1) == true ? "OVERFLOW" : "NO-OVERFLOW") << endl;
```

PS - I tried this program on MS Visual Studio professional 2015 on windows.

Comment: I looked at the linked questions, but they describe about multiplication of two integer. My case involved decimal numbers also.   And please have a look at the cout statements #1 and #4.  I need to know why they are failing? please answer. This question is not a duplicate of any question.

Comment: Hi, @πάντα ῥεῖ, I just need to know why #1 and #4 cout statements are failing. Can you please help me in this regard?

Comment: Use a debugger, single-step through the progam and see yourself.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question which considers to unsigned types as the parameters. Please don't be so eager to close questions as duplicates. Thank you.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Thank you so much. I appreciate you went through the question and reopened it again.

Comment: Could you give an example of values that require the else part of your code? I ask because using MSVC 2019, return ((A * B) > ULONG_MASK) seems to always give the correct answer.

Comment: Note that a `double` or any IEEE 754 representation is often not an exact number. Most of the time it's an approximation.

Comment: @JHBonarius: Ta, I'll clean up.

Comment: @fpiette: Indeed the simplistic implementation works on MSVC because type long is 32-bit even on 64-bit architectures in the Microsoft world.  On unix systems `return ((A * B) > ULONG_MASK)` fails for A and B equal to `pow(2,32)` (ie `0x1p32`).

Comment: Then you should tag your question with linux and tell which compiler you use. Stop talking about MSVC except to say it works without your else clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem if `ULONG_MAX` cannot be represented exactly as a `double`. For example if type `double` uses IEEE representation and `long` has 64 bits, `ULONG_MAX` be rounded to the next power of 2 when converted implicitly to `double` type for the comparison. Hence if this happens, the comparison should be `result >= ULONG_MAX` to ensure that `isGtThanULONG_MAX(0x1p32, 0x1p32)` returns `true`, instead of just `>` which works for 32-bit longs:

```
#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isGtThanULONG_MAX(double A, double B) {
    double result = A * B;
    if (ULONG_MAX + 1.0 == ULONG_MAX)
        return result >= ULONG_MAX;
    else
        return result > ULONG_MAX;
}
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind my edit. Have an upvote.

Comment: With 64-bit longs and 64-bit IEEE doubles, `(double)ULONG_MAX == (double)ULONG_MAX + 1`.

Comment: Sure? Try 65536 * 65535.99999.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Thank you for pointing this problem. I updated the solution with an explicit test for overflow, which is optimized by the compiler.

Comment: @chqrlie: I didn't understand this condition "if (ULONG_MAX + 1.0 == ULONG_MAX)". Can you tell me, On what values of A & B control will go inside the if condition?

Comment: @Jatin: if the value of `ULONG_MAX` is so large that it cannot be represented precisely as a `double`, eg: 64-bit `long` and IEEE `double` with a `53` bit mantissa, converting `ULONG_MAX` to `double` type rounds its value to `ULONG_MAX+1` which is a power of 2. On such platforms adding `1.0` to this value has no effect, and comparing `A * B > (double)ULONG_MAX` would be false  if the product `A * B` is exactly `pow(2,64)`. Testing `A * B >= (double)ULONG_MAX` catches this case, which occurs for example for `A = B = pow(2,32)`.

Comment: @chqrlie: thank you for explanation. Does your code also work on both windows & Linux/Unix flovours with gcc compiler. Just wanted to know if this code is portable?

Comment: @Jatin: this code should be portable to a variety of targets. You might get a warning about `ULONG_MAX + 1.0` having a precision issue, which is exactly the reason the test works :)